# iOS: Can (should) camera view be default view (that can launch other screens modally)?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Usually, the design pattern I see everywhere is like this:

- User is already on a view controller (VC1)
- User wants to pick or capture an image
- User either opens iOS camera (VC2) or photo library - usually using `presentModalViewController UIImagePickerController`
- From camera, he takes the picture, discards the camera view VC2 and shows the image back on landing screen VC1, using following delegate:

  ```
  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  ```

So far, this is what I am doing currently.

Now, my client realizes that the 1st screen VC1 is really a one-off type of screen and is not required always. It must load the first time. Later on, if at all, it must be launched from within VC2 (camera view controller).

Once discarded, every time, VC1 should reveal VC2.

This requirement leads me to believe that VC1 should be launched from VC2 modally.
But my experience so far with iOS camera view tells me the reverse, as I described in the first paragraph.

How should I deal with this?
Is the user's standpoint usual?

Is it feasible and workable that two VCs can be launched modally from each other?

If yes, what is the method?

If no, what is rational explanation that I could have for my client?

Comment: Not sure if I understand question correctly. It sounds like your customer always wants the camera view displayed to take pictures (except initial invoking of the app). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes as of now it turns out that way only, except for the initial load of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if this app needs to be published in app store, there is a high potential that apple would reject a app which continuously uses camera because these operations are battery intensive and can drain up the battery and system resources very fast. So while, client suggested approach may save user's touch input to select camera, but it heavy in terms of system resources. This explanation may help put up your point to customer.

Comment: +1 for good explanation. I will confirm if that is what he really wants and if there is an alternate way.